# How to disable some button of wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I m having a WPF DataGrid. in which there is one column contains edit button so how to enable or disable some button of datagrid progrmaticaly for example

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="80" Margin="2,-4,8,0" Name="grdQHDRShowAll" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="grdQHDRShowAll_SelectionChanged">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>

                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Button Click="Qhdr_CreateOrder_Click"  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=QuoteNo}" >Create Order</Button>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
```

the above code have a column with buttons so i want to know how to disable some buttons in rows depends on other columns data like true and false value of second column, if second column first row have data true then first column first rows button should be enable means depends on any column other column how to eable/disable button of datagrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If youre using the MVVM pattern you can bind the IsEnabled Property of the Button to a boolean Property of your VM or you use a converter to convert it to a boolean type:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=BoolProp}"/>
```

If not, you can bind it to an element using elementbinding:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=CellName, Path=BoolProp}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Button Content="Approve" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" Width="90" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding ApprovedCommand}" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In MVVM you create a property and make IsEnabled true or false on condition

Comment: Are you sure the mode should be `TwoWay`? I would expect an `InvalidOperationException` when binding this with mode equal to `TwoWay`.